# Can you choose the same option twice for Incendiary Command?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This card came up as a discussion.  One person was insisting you could choose the same option for [Incendiary Command](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIncendiary%20Command%5d) twice and there is no ruling from MTG.  Similar cards say you can only chose an option once. Does anyone know which is right?

Comment: You are commanded to choose two, if you choose one twice, you are not choosing two, you are choosing one, so no.

Answer (score 9):

No. If you could choose the same mode more than once, the card would explicitly state that (e.g. [Righteous Confluence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRighteous%20Confluence%5d)).

> 700.2d If a player is allowed to choose more than one mode for a modal spell
>   or ability, that player normally can’t choose the same mode more than once.
>   However, a few modal spells include the instruction “You may choose the same
>   mode more than once.” If a particular mode is chosen multiple times, the spell
>   is treated as if that mode appeared that many times in sequence. If that mode
>   requires a target, the same player or object may be chosen as the target for
>   each of those modes, or different targets may be chosen.

[Source](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Modal_spell).